# Completing individual box plot with two rows of data, compairing positive against negative

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

I am still fairly new to R.  Please can someone help me with a query.

How do I complete individual box plots on my data?  I need to compare the positive against the negative for each row.  There are 195 columns.

The data look like this: (The positive is under the negative, so two row and up to 195 columns, and I need to boxplot each column)

```
                     1    2    3    4    5     6   7   etc 
Negative            1.1  2.1  2.2  3.1  5.66 8.99 5.11 etc
Positive            2.1  5.6  5.7  3.0  6.1  8.1  6.2  etc
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: boxplot for each column? There are only two numbers for each column. How can you plot a boxplot for just two numbers? I assume you want a boxplot for Positive as one group and Negative as the other group. Please see my answer.

Comment: Hello.  Thanks for your reply.  Yes I want to boxplot for positive and negative.

Answer (score 1):

```
require(tidyverse) # dplyr() and ggplot2()
# your data
data <- data.frame(negative = c( 1.1,  2.1,  2.2,  3.1,  5.66, 8.99, 5.11),
               positive = c(2.1,  5.6,  5.7,  3.0,  6.1,  8.1,  6.2))
# we gather to have one long column with values and one with the "class"
data <- data %>% gather(class) # you can name here the class column
# use ggplot to plot the data
ggplot(data, aes(y = value, x = class)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

Please provide a reproducible example text time, see this: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: It has 2 columns, "negative" and "positive", with `gather` I get the long format.

Comment: Hello.  Many thanks for reply.  There seems to be an error in the gather function. Error in gather(., class) : could not find function "gather"

Comment: You need to install some packages first, use: `install.packages("tidyverse")`

Comment: `gather()` and `ggplot()` are "extra" function, not provided with the base R packages. You need to install their respective libraries first to use them.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @LieslCarr Please consider to accept the answer you think are relevant and useful.

Answer (score 1):

Your data frame is in wide format, which is difficult to work with. We can first convert it to long format.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  gather(Column, Value, -rowname)
```

After that, you can use the `ggplot2` package to plot the data as Riccardo Lavelli suggested. Here I showed another option, which is the `bwplot` function from the `lattice` package.

```
library(lattice)

bwplot(Value ~ rowname, dat2)
```

[image]

You can also consider to use the base R `boxplot` function.

```
boxplot(Value ~ rowname, dat2)
```

[image]

You can also consider the `ggboxplot` from the `ggpubr` package.

```
library(ggpubr)

ggboxplot(dat2, x = "rowname", y = "Value")
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "                     1    2    3    4    5     6   7 
Negative            1.1  2.1  2.2  3.1  5.66 8.99 5.11
Positive            2.1  5.6  5.7  3.0  6.1  8.1  6.2",
                  header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks.  The original data has 195 columns, is there a way I can enter it without typing it manually?

Comment: @LieslCarr My solution does not need any manual typing. So it should not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help. Please consider to accept the post as the answer if it solves your question.

Comment: @LieslCarr https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work